# Code First is not generating DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

i am learning EF, i am following [simple-code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx) example. i do as mentioned in the tutorial. but when i run the application it does not generate the DB as mentioned in tutorial. could experts can tell does this tutorial is making mistake or i am doing any mistake.

my code is here:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
        {
            Student stud = new Student() { Studentname = "Ram", StudentdateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4) };

            ctx.Students.Add(stud);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

 public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}

  public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Studentname { get; set; }
    public DateTime StudentdateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    public Standard Standard { get; set; }

}

 public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {

    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: EF is almost certainly producing an error message, unless it isn't running at all.

Comment: here try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it is not generating any error. that's why i am here..sorry if it is being unclear to you.

Comment: @kyle, that's okay.. i will try that too. but my question is why the above code is not working when i did as mentioned in the tutorial. is there my mistake or tutorial has wrong code. If tutorial has wrong code. then we will send them email to make correct changes to make it running

Comment: @RamSingh Do you have the right connectionstring?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, according to concept, if you do not provide connectstring, it will create mdf file in your solution that was i supposing.

Comment: @RamSingh I'm not entirely sure on this but I think you still need to install sql express for that

Comment: @RamSingh You did the migrations? I see it's not included in the tutorial for some reason (or perhaps it's not necessary anymore?)